# Is there any flow diagram or wai-aria "debugger" about how the reader should read the web page?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm working on the accessibility of a page.

I think that I understand the examples I see at [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/) and I keep reading it.

I'm pretty lost now trying [NVDA Reader](https://www.nvaccess.org/) will read a modal form deep inside a `<div><div>..` "lasagna"

My Question is: **Is there any aria "debugger" that could tell me why or why not is reading some word or why it stop reads?** or, which is the best way to approach this "debug" job?

Is it very inefficient to change aria-* attributes randomly...?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's not really any debugger for aria or accessibility. All assistive tech (NVDA, JAWS, ChromeVox, etc) have slightly different behavior, and it also depends on the browser and OS. There isn't a debugger or tool that will tell us what should happen as each tech combiniation has its own interaction and result. It drives us all crazy to be sure.

The closest we can get is to determine what 'should' happen in a best case scenario. For that, we have examples from the W3, Mozilla documentation, and other reputable sources.
Best most of us can do is test on the platforms that 'most' users will be using and make sure those are solid.

To help debug your particular case, you can try checking the accessibility tree in something like the Chrome inspector. Open the Accessibility tab in the inspector (near Styles, Computed, Event Listeners, etc), and it should tell you what assistive tech will be able to see (at least, while using Chrome). If you're expecting a text node and you see 'Ignored. Accessibility node not exposed', that's a clue.

As a side note, NVDA only reads a line or so at a time if you're on a massive block of text. You'll need to keep hitting down arrow to hear the rest. I assume that's not your issue, but FYI just in case.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean. About the aside note, In fact I'm not 'hearing' at NVDA, I'm watching at the "NVDA Speech Viewer" and I think in a massive block It runs till the las line the reader would read with enough time.